# COM-like apartment threading model for ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

Question for ObjectiveC gurus w/ some WinAPI background:

Is there support for COM-like apartment threading model in ObjectiveC?

- Class A is **single-threaded**: all objects of class A are created in one specific thread, and all message handlers are invoked in that thread
- Class B is **multi-threaded**: objects of class B can be created in any caller thread, and all message handlers are invoked only in original thread used to create the object
- Class C is **free-threaded**: objects of class C can be created in any caller thread, message handlers can be invoked in any thread

My thoughts are: since ObjectiveC is about messages, COM+ like multi-threading can be easily achieved. Or not?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for single-threaded or multi-threaded objects as defined by your question.

In Mac OS X or iOS apps, you'd probably want to use GCD queues to enforce these policies yourself.  I recommend the [WWDC 2011 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) named “Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice” and “Mastering Grand Central Dispatch” for some great advice on applying GCD.